# Help me prove a simple linear algebra problem

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a ($p\times 1$) vector $a$, I need to show that
$$
a'(aa’)^{-1}a = 1
$$
My first intuition was to apply a trace operator, using the property that the trace of a scalar is the scalar itself. So:
$$
tr[a'(aa’)^{-1}a]
$$
But then I am a little stuck, I thing that it’s also useful to use the property that $$tr(aa’)=a’a$$
But I need some extra steps to arrive to the desired result.

Comment: What is $a'{}{}$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I believe the transposed vector

Comment: Then the question doesn't make sense for $p > 1$. The matrix $aa'$ has rank $1$, so it is not invertible for $p > 1$.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to transpose the first vector, now it makes sense

Comment: Okay I just realized how to do it, it was indeed quite simple. Simply note that $a’(aa’)^{-1}a=1 \iff aa’(aa’)^{-1}a=a \implies a = a$ so equality holds.

Comment: That still doesn't work. $(aa')^{-1}$ does not exist.

Comment: @Tzimmo if $a$ is a row vector, then $aa'$ is its norm squared, represented as a $1\times 1$ matrix. The "only" problem is if the sum of $a$'s elements is zero. But obviously that's implied not to be the case.

Comment: But $a$ is $1 \times p$, not $p \times 1$.

Comment: Also, $a'(aa')^{-1}a$ is not a number if $a$ is a row vector. It is a $p \times p$-matrix.